# Email confirmation token is not sent to user mail in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, email, token, confirm

I used this line of code to send a confirmation-mail-token to a registering user's mail:

> var token = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

but nothing is gotten in the user email.

I tried Gmail and Outlook accounts.

I tried "Less secure app access".

I logged the token to a file and it indeed logged in the file. This shows apparently,  that the token is sent to the mail account, but not accepted by the account.

Here is a quotation from my code :

> 

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        { // ModelState will give the error remarks onto the form if the model fields don't fit the criteries /not valid.
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Copy data from RegisterViewModel to ApplicationUser 
                var user = new ApplicationUser 
                {
                    UserName = model.Email,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    City = model.City
                };

                // Store user data in AspNetUsers database table
                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);// in this signature of the method there is  a password indeed

                // If user is successfully created, sign-in the user using
                // SignInManager and redirect to index action of HomeController
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {  // creating a token which will be sent within the confirmation link.
                    var token = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    var confirmationLink = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account",
                        new { userId = user.Id, token = token }, Request.Scheme);
                    
                    logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, confirmationLink);  // to c:\DemoLogs
```

> 

I run it in debug mode , and checked the mail address in 'user.Email' which it is appeared correctly.

Comment: did you get any errormessage? did you send the email in code? I dont see it in your provided code.

Comment: Thank you.  The userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync function is supposed to call a set of functions that take the user's email address from 'user' parameter , create a token and send it to the user's mail.   I initialized the 'user' properties by the parameter 'model' of 'Register' function.   the 'model' is fulfilled by the register form fields , which the user submits. One of the fields is the email address.  For more information about creating and sending a confirmation token  : https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2019/10/how-tokens-are-generated-and-validated.html